# Load js model into three js project

Tags: json, three.js, 3dsmax

I used the following code (which is not mine, it's taken from this article http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-export-a-rigged-animated-model-from-3ds-max-three-js/) in my project and tried to load my model. But the ptoblem is that the author uses animated skinned mesh, I have a simple model. I copied his complete demo page code to my project, changed the path to the js model and it doesn't show up. What should I adjust to make it work?

```
        var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer, objects;
        var particleLight, pointLight;
        var mesh, wiggly;

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        loader.load( './humpback-whale-animated-threejs-max-exporter.js', function ( geometry, materials ) {

    var originalMaterial = materials[ 0 ];
    originalMaterial.skinning = true;

    mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, originalMaterial );
    mesh.scale.set( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 );

            var animation = new THREE.Animation(
                mesh,
                geometry.animation
            );
            animation.play();

            init();
            animate();

        });

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

    scene.add( mesh );

            // Lights

            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc ) );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(/*Math.random() * 0xffffff*/0xeeeeee );
            directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );

            pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 4 );
            scene.add( pointLight );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render() {

            var delta = clock.getDelta();

            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update( delta );

            camera.position.x = Math.cos( 0.5 ) * 20;
            camera.position.y = 5;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin( 0.5 ) * 20;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

I know there are different loaders in three.js and I don't know which one to use for a simple static textured mesh.

Comment: find another tutorial that does not use a skinned mesh. Plenty of [examples here](https://threejs.org/examples/)

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected, not many of the examples load a JSON model, but https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_json_claraio does. There is also the [JSONLoader docs](https://threejs.org/docs/api/loaders/JSONLoader.html). My first comment was meant to encourage you to do some research as doing a search on google for "three.js load json" yields many results

Comment: Look at the source code, or look at the JSONLoader class docs that I linked to. from 3ds max you could also export an .obj and use the OBJLoader class which is what I did on my last three.js project

Comment: It was a couple of years ago,  you will have to experiment yourself

Comment: ok, I'll answer over there